# Adding things into a list in the same order

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
  while n:
     i += 1
     istart = raw_input("Interview Start Time: ")
     iend= raw_input("Interview End Time: ")
     ipeople= raw_input("What are the interviewer names: ")
     itype= raw_input("What is the interview type: ")
     lis.append({istart, iend, ipeople, itype})
     n-=1
  for i in lis:
    print i
```

IT PRODUCES THIS FOR EXAMPLE

```
set(['9', '8', 'problem', 'john smith'])
set(['john deer', '10', '9', 'fit'])
```

How can I make sure that things are appended in the same order every time can I even do that with a list in Python? The end goal is to write this to a file called mydoc.doc which I have set up but I need it formatted into a table like display to display this in a nice table format thats why the consistency in each sublist is key. Is there a python library that could help with creating a table. I know I could just use dashes but I need a nicer html style table.

Comment: Please fix the indent.

Comment: For what is `i` needed? Use a `for`-Loop instead of `while`.

Comment: why are you using a set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose a `tuple` as a datastructure instead of a `set`. `tuple` will save the order and `set` will not. That is change the `{` and `}` in append statement to `(` and `)`. This will append a `tuple`. Apart from that if `istart` and `iend` is the same, then `set` will store only one copy.

```
lis.append((istart, iend, ipeople, itype))
```

Sample output

```
Interview Start Time: 8
Interview End Time: 9
What are the interviewer names: john smith
What is the interview type: problem
Interview Start Time: 9
Interview End Time: 10
What are the interviewer names: john deer
What is the interview type: fit
('8', '9', 'john smith', 'problem')
('9', '10', 'john deer', 'fit')
```

Refer -

- [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)
- [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

  > A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2):

A `set`, like a `dict`, uses a hash table so it has **no** order among its items -- and that's **exactly** what you're asking for with the braces in

```
lis.append({istart, iend, ipeople, itype})
```

Since you care about the items' ordering, it's absurd to use a `set` -- use, instead, a type that **does** maintain item ordering, such as a `list` (square brackets):

```
lis.append([istart, iend, ipeople, itype])
```

or a `tuple` (parentheses):

```
lis.append((istart, iend, ipeople, itype))
```

In either case, to generate from the resulting list a nice HTML table you could for example install and use http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html .

Once you **have** installed that module, and with `lis` as a list of sublists:

```
import HTML
table = HTML.table(lis)
print table
```

does it all for you.  (You probably want a first sub-list that gives the column names, tho).

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
    n = True
    sublis = []
    while n:
        istart = raw_input("Interview Start Time: ")
        iend = raw_input("Interview End Time: ")
        ipeople = raw_input("What are the interviewer names: ")
        itype = raw_input("What is the interview type: ")
        sublis.append([istart,iend,ipeople,itype])
        n = False
    lis.append(sublis)
```

So use it as a list format instead which preserves order.